# How can I create a bootable windows 10 installation on a usb stick with linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, bootable-media

How can I create a bootable windows 10 installation on an usb stick using a linux machine?

Suppose I have a windows 10 iso file on my linux machine.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1240477/make-bootable-windows-usb-on-linux/1240493

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool called [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) to create a [bootable Windows 10 USB drive under Linux](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/tool-to-create-bootable-windows-usb.html)

[image]

Here select an ISO or DVD as source, your target and click on `Install`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool called [MKUSB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create a [bootable Windows 10 USB drive under Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive).

[image]
[image]

Just select the option W - "extracting Windows installer" select the intended Windows 10 ISO, then the target drive.

Answer (score -1):

There's a few good answers to this question elsewhere on the Internet (including superuser). Here's a short summary:

(Recent windows ISOs are not of the kind that can be dd'd into a USB stick and they'll just boot (ElTorito). They are now UDF formatted.)
- Prepare the USB stick by wiping it and creating a new partition table with a FAT32 (or NTFS) partition;
- Copy all the contents of the windows ISO onto the USB stick's partition;
- Install a bootloader using ms-sys;

[Make bootable windows USB on linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1240477/make-bootable-windows-usb-on-linux/1240493)